# Can I bruteforce a partitioned encrypted Usb drive?

Tags: catalina

I partitioned a kingston datatraveler g4 and encrypted one partition. I don't remember the whole password and read things online about bruteforce cracking but don't understand how to apply it.
I read that I don't have a core storage uuid because it is partitioned. Anyone with a simple solution?

[image]

Comment: Bruteforcing basically means "try every possible password". Depending on the length of it (or the length of the unknown part at least) this will take very very long, even if you find a way to script it so it can run unattended.

Comment: How did you encrypt it actually? Directly in Finder or with a separate tool?

Comment: Directly in finder. I think the password is only 9 digits long

Comment: 9 chars and assuming base64 (numbers, a-z; A-Z, symbols, punct.) is 9^64=1.18x10^61 combinations. You’ll be brute forcing for decades.